# Pyinstaller cannot import pynput module

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pynput

Hey ive tried coding a script in which i use pynput to detect keybinds being pressed. It works fine itself but sadly once i try to use pyinstaller to make it into an exe file the following error pops up once i try to run it.
[image: screenshot of the error]

I have tried looking up the problem but have not found any working solutions.
I have also read through pyinstaller's documentation but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#use this `pip install pynput==1.6.8`